# query component stuck in loading state react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

We are using apollo graphql client in react native project. This Query never completes although it's working fine in IOS device & android emulator but not on actual android device.

```js
<Query query="{GET_BRANDS}" fetchpolicy="network-only" client="{xxx}">{({data,loading,error})=>{ if(data && data.getBrand){ return(<brandlist value="{data.getBrand}" navigation="{this.props.navigation}" scrollintoview="{this.props.scrollIntoView}/">) } else if (error) {return<text allowfontscaling="{false}">{JSON.stringify(error)}</text>} else if (loading) {return<text allowfontscaling="{false}">Loading...</text>} else return null }}</Query>
```